# Unable to use CMake to Generate OpenCV Project

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, opencv, cmake

Every time I try to build, I get the error:

CMake Error: The source directory "E:/Code/Test" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.

Which doesn't make a ton of sense, because I very clearly have CMakeLists.txt included in that directory.  I tried looking for this problem on the internet, but it seems that I might be the only person to ever have this issue.  Has anyone run across this issue before?

Is there an easier way to be integrating OpenCV?  I've got a copy of Visual Studio, but the OpenCV wiki says that it's not supported any longer.

I'm on Windows 7, using the CMake-GUI

The guide I've followed to try and get started with this can be found here: http://redkiing.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/opencv-and-visual-studio-2010-with-cmake/

**EDIT**

I ended up using the prebuilt OpenCV for Windows.

Comment: could it be a problem of windows slashes (\\) versus linux slashes (/)?

Comment: No, I'm using the CMake-GUI and it automatically changes \ to /.
I was able to use the tool to build OpenCV, but it's not working on the test project.

Comment: Can you definitely open E:/Code/Test/CMakeLists.txt in a text editor? If so, which version of CMake are you using?

Comment: Yes, I can definitely open it.  I'm using CMake v2.8.8

Comment: I have the similar problem. I am using MacOSx 10.8.2 and following [this tutorial of Stanford's](http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/Tutorial-2-OpenCV-for-Android-Setup-Macintosh.pdf). My problem occurs on the 3rd page '3. Build OpenCV Library' part.

Comment: My solution is not applicable to your situation, so I suggest you open your own question.  Also, not being a Mac user myself, I can't say for certain, but doesn't OSX support the 'make' command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can definitely open E:/Code/Test/CMakeLists.txt in a text editor, then this is a bug with CMake GUI I guess.  You could try re-installing CMake.  If that still fails, you could ask on the [CMake mailing list](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/mailing.html) and/or [file a bug report](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/my_view_page.php).

If you want to try without the CMake GUI, you can open a Visual Studio command prompt and work from there.

- Go to build directory (where to build the binaries - create it first if need be)

  ```
  cd E:/Code/Test
  mkdir build
  cd E:/Code/Test/build
  ```
- Invoke CMake with the appropriate generator.  To see the full list of generators, run `cmake -h`

  ```
  cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 10"
  ```
- Show options

  ```
  cmake .. -L
  ```
- Set options.  e.g. to switch `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` off, do:

  ```
  cmake .. -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF
  ```

Any options set this way are cached, and will remain unchanged for any further runs of CMake.  If you want to see help info for each cached option, do `cmake .. -LH`.

The end result will be a VS solution E:/Code/Test/buildOpenCV.sln

Comment: You're right, this appears to be a bug.  It returns the same error for both the GUI and the command line interface.

Comment: I followed your recommendations as closely as I could, but I had no luck.  There is, of course, always the chance of compatibility issues.

Comment: Unlucky.  I think the mailing list is the best place to try now, I'm afraid I'm out of suggestions :-(

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem,

I just rename the file by copy and past (CMakeLists.txt).

and it works

Comment: It did work for me. Thanks (make copy of the file, delete old one and rename copy back to original name)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the CMake-Gui, which should be located in the CMake/bin-Directory. With this tool, you can specify the sources location and settings.

Comment: I actually am using the CMakue-Gui.  I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: Hm, im a little confused. Are you trying to build opencv or a test project? In the second case, i would not recommend to use CMake to create a solution, but visual studio itself, adding the libs and include-paths in the project settings.

Comment: I'm using the guide here: http://redkiing.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/opencv-and-visual-studio-2010-with-cmake/

It tells me to be using CMake in both cases.  I tried including the libs on their own before, but I ran into other issues when I tried to actually run the program.

Comment: Yes, this is, what they say, but i think, before dangling with cmake, you could simply do it by yourself. In the guide you linked to, the result is a solution file too, which is configured for opencv, but i think, if you use the tutorial on willowgarage, which is meant to be deprecated, you would achieve the same: a project, which can be used for opencv.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work, as I'm asked to reference several directories that don't exist.  It might work if I was to simply download OpenCV 2.1.0, but I'd rather not resort to that.